# sql server: How to detect changed rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a trigger to detect whether a row has been changed in SQL Server.  My current approach is to loop through each field, apply COLUMNS_UPDATED() to detect whether UPDATE has been called, then finally compare the values of this field for the same row (identified by PK) in inserted vs deleted.

I want to eliminate the looping from the procedure.  Probably I can dump the content of inserted and deleted into one table, group on all columns, and pick up the rows with count=2.  Those rows will count as unchanged.

The end goal is to create an audit trail: 
1) Track user and timestamp
2) Track insert, delete and REAL changes

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is this in the context of a Trigger?

Comment: Yes.  I looked at SQL Server's built in solutions - they don't satisfy all the requirements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Create Generic SQL Server Stored Procedure To Perform Inserts Into Audit Table Based on Inserted and Deleted In Trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873335/how-to-create-generic-sql-server-stored-procedure-to-perform-inserts-into-audit)

Comment: it is not a duplicate.  my current solution implements the idea in the aforementioned post.  I want a solution that detects a change, but not tracking the details of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of looping you can use [BINARY_CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx) to compare entire rows between the inserted and deleted tables, and then act accordingly.

**Example**

```
Create table SomeTable(id int, value varchar(100))

Create table SomeAudit(id int, Oldvalue varchar(100), NewValue varchar(100))


Create trigger tr_SomTrigger  on SomeTable for Update 
as
begin
        insert into SomeAudit 
        (Id, OldValue, NewValue)
        select i.Id, d.Value, i.Value 
        from
        (
            Select Id, Value, Binary_CheckSum(*) Version from Inserted
        ) i
        inner join 
        (
            Select Id, Value, Binary_CheckSum(*) Version from Deleted
        ) d
        on i.Id = d.Id and i.Version <> d.Version


End 

Insert into sometable values (1, 'this')
Update SomeTable set Value = 'That'
Select * from SomeAudit
```

Comment: Do you know how can I use this function in a WHERE clause?  I have something like this:  
 WHERE BINARY_CHECKSUM(i.*) <> BINARY_CHECKSUM(d.*)

Comment: To use it in a where clause I'd recommend including it in a subquery, and then doing then doing the where clause against the subquery, I added a sample.

Comment: NOTE: Some types of columns are excluded from the BINARY_CHECKSUM() comparison.  From MS doco "BINARY_CHECKSUM ignores columns of noncomparable data types in its computation. Noncomparable data types include text, ntext, image, cursor, xml,..".